# SystemModeler considered Mathematica related Wolfram product?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question about SystemModeler which is Wolfram's modeling tool and comes tightly integrated with Mathematica, yet I got people saying this was OT. Are SystemModeler questions alright? I would note that there is a system-modeler tag, so I assumed I could ask a question about SystemModeler if there was a tag for it.

Comment: Really a question for the Mathematica meta site, no?

Comment: I am closing this post because one already exists asking the same question. But I do think it is worth re-examining the original question.

Answer (score 2):

I think the real question here is whether there is enough expertise and interest in SystemModeler among the participants of this site. I, personally, have neither the expertise nor the interest, so I would vote to keep SystemModeler questions off the site. But that's a sample of one. If enough participants come forward here and indicate an opposing position, I would be willing to vote to reopen your question.

To make my position completely clear: I think admitting SystemModeler question would spread us out too thin. I believe we already spread very thin just covering the questions we already get. I would emphasize that this just my opinion and that I could belong to a very small minority (maybe me alone).

Comment: I agree. With the Wolfram Community site now active, I think we can fairly say that, since SystemModeler is not one of our strong suits, there are better places to ask about it--to the extent that we can be reasonably sure that such questions will not be answered well here and thus deem them off topic. But, as it's a fairly new product, that may well change in the future. I wouldn't want to unduly discourage users from asking their questions here if they strongly anticipate getting a useful answer. Questions won't be closed immediately, and can be re-opened, so it's worth a try if so.